# Module not showing in modules list for installing

Tags: module, install

Am trying to install Flag Master addon.

https://github.com/mithra62/flag-master

Did copy the extracted folder to third_party folder as per the install instructions.

However the module doesn't show up in the modules list for it to be installed.

Am using EE 2.10..1

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Am using EE 2.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files should be located inside system/expressionengine/third_party/flag_master/ folder, not directly in third_party folder. Please check that.

Comment: The files are in the 'flag-master-master' folder inside 'third_party' folder Yuri.

Comment: I renamed the folder 'flag-master-master' to 'flag_master' and it worked!

Comment: However, after installing, and when trying to access Flag Master module, there is an error. Unable to load the requested class: flag_master_member_data

Comment: Commented line 50 in Flag_master_channel_data.php 
' $this->EE->load->library('flag_master_member_data');'

Guess the newer versions don't need that!

Comment: It still asks for a license key, which I don't have, since it was not downloaded from devot-ee.com and was downloaded from Github. Waiting for the developer Eric Lamb to respond. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure the folder you place in the third_party directory matches the package name.

From the Github repo, you can see that the files are called xxx.flag_master.php, so therefore the directory needs to be named flag_master. I assume the because the Github repo is called flag-master, the folder is being named that instead.